# Объектно-ориентированное программирование в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь реализовать класс Order (заказ), который имеет следующие свойства и методы:
Свойство orderNumber (номер заказа) - число, уникальный номер заказа.
Свойство products (продукты) - массив, содержащий список продуктов в заказе.
Метод addProduct(product) - принимает объект product и добавляет его в список продуктов заказа.
Метод getTotalPrice() - возвращает общую стоимость заказа, основанную на ценах продуктов.

Мое решение:

```
class Product {
    constructor(name, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    } 
}

class Order {
    constructor(orderNumber, products) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        this.products = products;
    }

    addProduct(product) {

    }

    getTotalPrice() {
        
    }
}
```

// то что должно получиться в итоге

```
const order = new Order(12345);
    
const product1 = new Product("Phone", 500);
order.addProduct(product1);
    
const product2 = new Product("Headphones", 100);
order.addProduct(product2);
    
console.log(order.getTotalPrice()); // Вывод: 600
```

Пробовал к классу Order присвоить данные из Product с помощью (class Order extends Product), но получается ерунда(((

Comment: Проблема-то в чём?  "ерунда" - это не описание проблемы

Comment: Вы вообще ничего не написали. Вы дали шаблон кода. Ваши попытки где? Или хотите, чтобы за вас написали?

Answer (score 0):

`this.products` - это массив. Соответственно в методе `addProduct` нужно класть `product`  в этот массив

В методе `getTotalPrice` нужно пробежаться по массиву `this.products` и просуммировать все `price` из каждого элемента этого массива (каждого продукта). Вернуть результат этого сложения